# NestJS changing param names received in post request

Tags: node.js, nestjs

My goal is for an endpoint to receive `firstName` in the JSON request and save `first_name` in my DB.

I created a dto outlining the params I want to receive for the endpoint like so:

```
@IsNotEmpty()
@Expose({ name: 'firstName' })
first_name: string;
```

[vscode intellisense snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZtUc.png)

vscode even picks up that the prop name should be first_name.

However when I console.log it I receive this: (`firstName` instead of `first_name`)

```
{
  email: 'test@test.com',
  password: 'test',
  firstName: 'first',
  lastName: 'last'
}
```

(My DB entity also has the field set up as first_name and it's throwing an error)

Comment: I think you are transforming the field_name here `{ name: 'firstName' }`, just use `@Expose()` decorator with no additional parameters, should work

Comment: I removed that and I got the error that
`"first_name should not be empty"`

Comment: I figured it out, needed to set
`@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))`
on the controller

Comment: How about using SnakeCase Strategy in TypeORM? Using this it will automatically transform camelCase to snake_case.

Comment: Yeah I figured out I could pass `{name: first_name}` inside the `@Column()` decorator and decided to go with this approach after all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation pipe's `transform: true` option needs to be set so that the pipe returns the class instance rather than just the validated json