# NestJs serialize params with different names

Tags: node.js, json, parsing, nestjs, dto

Hy Folks,

I'm studying NestJs and I'm facing a uncommon case when use a serialization with DTO and JSON.

My Json come with follow param:

```
{
   "category": 1
}
```

But I need use this property as "type", so in my DTO is:

```
export class CreateClassDto {
    @IsNumber()
    type: CustomType;
}
```

How can I parse the "category" param from Json to param "type" on my DTO?

When I change the parameter name in DTO my Entity not parse, the service crash and I can't save indo my DB.

In Swift language I can use something like that:

```
struct Entity: Codable {
    let type: CustomType

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type = "category"
    }
}
```

Is there something like this or a decorator to say that my param received need to be my internal param?

I tried use @Expose(), but I need that "category" to be transformed in "type" for my DB and for my application.

I read this post:
[NestJS changing param names received in post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75022347/nestjs-changing-param-names-received-in-post-request)

But not understand so much.

Some one has an exemplo to do it?

Regard

Answer (score 0):

I dont think javascript/typescript have that capability of swift as of now. But here is my proposed workaround for your situation. I have been using this technique in all of my projects, to keeps things tidy and separate.

Dto

```
export class CreateClassDto {
  @IsNumber()
  category: CustomType;

  static toJSON(data: CreateClassDto) {
    return {
      type: data.category,
    };
  }
}
```

In Controller

```
async createClass(@Body() body: CreateClassDto) {
    const data = CreateClassDto.toJSON(body);
    // now you can pass the data to the respective service
    await this.classService.save(data)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi itssajan, it's not the real problem, the problem is that I have a system that return to me a parameter called "category" in the returned JSON, but my system has and need to have parameter "type" instead, so when I serialize the JSON I need transforme category (external param) to my type (internal param) in service layer.
So, the controller not affected, because this I need something like @jsonproperty used in java, a simple solution just to said to my DTO that the field has other name when received.
I don't know is a possible, but in another languages and frameworks are....

Comment: Other thing that I tried, I've created a static function on my entity to make a "custom" entity using my DTO, but I don't know why the relationship ManyToMany stop to save on DB even doing insert the parameter into a object directly.

Comment: oh! i see. Are you using TypeORM ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using TypeORM.